# H2DB: Using the AND condition causing error in local memory

Tags: h2, h2db

I have a table called classification that has a column named product_id and a column named node_id.

I'm trying to make a simple query in the h2 console as so:

```
select * from classification 
    where product_id =1 and node_id = 01010101
```

It gives me the following error

```
General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
select * from classification where product_id =1 and node_id = 01010101 [50000-164]
```

Running the statements individually with the and brings up the required result. For example:

```
select * from classification 
        where product_id =1
```

As soon as I put an and statement in, it gives me that error.
The H2 documentation states for the AND Condition that

> Value or condition.
>
> Example:
>
> ID=1 AND NAME='Hi'

I am unsure what I'm doing wrong here. Am I using AND incorrectly?

Stack Trace

```
select * from classification
where product_ID = 1 AND node_ID = 05051103;
General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
select * from classification
where product_ID = 1 AND node_ID = 05051103 [50000-164] HY000/50000 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path"; SQL statement:
select * from classification
where product_ID = 1 AND node_ID = 05051103 [50000-164]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:281)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:191)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:173)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:152)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.getResult(WebApp.java:1311)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.query(WebApp.java:1001)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.query(WebApp.java:977)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:217)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:164)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doGet(WebServlet.java:118)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doPost(WebServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.processFilterChain(UrlMappingsFilter.java:377)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:228)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:241)
    at org.h2.index.MultiVersionCursor.next(MultiVersionCursor.java:135)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.next(IndexCursor.java:238)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:353)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:513)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:618)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:297)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:267)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:82)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:187)
```

Comment: You are using a very old version of H2 (build 164). Did you try with a newer version? And could you post the stack trace?

Comment: 01010101 is just a random value from the table.

I posted the stack trace in the main post, but I don't know how useful it is. I didn't try in a newer version, I have no control over that currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very old version of H2, 1.0.64 from 2007. This issue is fixed with a more recent version.

Comment: Well finally got it resolved. I don't know why we were using such an old version.